# Angular 2 - decompress downloaded gzipped file

Tags: angular, gzip, compression

I am downloading a file from our server. The file is the result of a series of processes that apply the compression algorithm twice. The browser automatically undo one layer of compression but give me a response that is still a gzipped file:

```
return this.http.get(url, new RequestOptions({headers: this.authHeader(), search}))
        .catch(err => Observable.of(err))
        .map((response: Response) => {
                // add url property to the returned JSON object
                let jsonObject = response.json();

                // IF COMPRESSED DO SOMETHING HERE!

                return jsonObject;
            }
            return null;
        })
        ;
}
```

to recap the problem is that the response is still compressed contents that I need to parse (decompress) locally. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Is it not possible to have the server unzip it once before sending?

Comment: Unfortunately not without making the downloading process too long. File are really big and we would rather try to run last decompression file locally.

Comment: This will be difficult then since the server is were the unzip should happen. You may have some luck using this https://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/ but no promises.

Comment: Have a look at this https://github.com/JonatanSCS/Angular-2-Tutorial/tree/master/node_modules/unzip-response